# How to prevent cucumber feature tests from affecting elasticsearch index in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, lucene, cucumber

I am very new to using elasticsearch in a rails application and am using the chewy gem to implement it.

I have everything set up and working correctly and I thought that the chewy gem was making seperate index for test and development environments due to the `Chewy.settings = {prefix: 'test'}` configuration.

My RSpec tests run fine and do not cause any problems in development but when I run my feature tests I get an error in development when searching.

```
undefined method `image_url' for nil:NilClass
```

I believe this is because the elasticsearch index is getting overwritten by the tests and then the records have been deleted from the test db so are returning nil.

However I am not sure why this is happening in development as I thought that development and test environments had seperate elasticsearch index.

To fix this I have to run **rake chewy:reset:all**

I am not very familiar with how elasticsearch functions so would appreciate anyone shedding a little light on what is happening behind the scenes and how to set up an elasticsearch index for the test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hard coding the index prefix as "test" for **all** environments so the index was named the same thing for both test and development environments.

The correct config is

> Chewy.settings = {prefix: Rails.env}

Which will add a "Test" prefix for the index in the test environment and "Development" prefix for the index in the Development environment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to separate `development` and `test` so that they use different ports. The example given in the [Chewy docs](https://github.com/toptal/chewy) is probably what you need:

```
# config/chewy.yml
# separate environment configs
test:
  host: 'localhost:9250'
  prefix: 'test'
development:
  host: 'localhost:9200'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Taking a look at the .yml file gave me the mental jog to realise that I'm hard coding all the prefixs to "test" in the config setting! changing this to "Chewy.setting = {prefix: Rails.env}" did the trick :)